# sproc using 'for xml' and then ExecuteXmlReader in C# -> "Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values."

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have some code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ToString()))
            {
                SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

                command.CommandText = "sproc1";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                command.Parameters.Add(
                        new SqlParameter("@Param1",2));

                connection.Open();
                doc.Load(command.ExecuteXmlReader());
            }
```

which loads an xml document from a sproc. I get:

Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.

when the sproc returns null as it uses:

```
for xml raw, type, root('rows')
```

to transform the table results into xml.

How can I avoid this? Either in my sql code or deal with it in C#?

Thanks.

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best work around I have found so far is to use this in my sql code:

```
DECLARE @XML XML;
...
SELECT @XML = (select
...
for xml raw, type, root('rows'))
...
select case when @XML is not null then @XML else '<rows></rows>' end
```

Comment: looks like good work around.. nothing wrong in returning default value instead of null. :)

Answer (score 0):

OK.. what about this code?

```
connection.Open();
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
DataTable table = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(table);
if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        XmlWriter writer = XmlTextWriter.Create(stream);
        table.WriteXml(writer);
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
        doc.Load(reader);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this before - command.ExecuteXmlReader throws an exception: {"Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values."}

Comment: @csetzkorn - sorry thought Load threw execption. Will try to find alternative.

Comment: Thanks. I had to give the table a name but get: Root element is missing now

Comment: @csetzkorn - sorry.. try to mess around little more with the DataAdapter/DataTable idea, I'll try it myself when I'll have some time..